# Question About Concave Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

It easy to prove that no non-constant positive concave function exists (for example by integrating:
$ u'' \leq 0 \to u' \leq c \to u \leq cx+c_2 $ and since $u>0$ , we obviously get a contradiction.

Can this result be generalized to $ \Bbb R^2 $ and the Laplacian?  Is there an easy way to see this? (i.e.- no non-constant positive real-valued function with non-positive l
Laplacian exists)

Thanks!

Comment: You want that to be strictly concave. Otherwise $f(x)\equiv 1$ is positive and concave. ($c=0$)

Comment: Also, you assume that the function is twice diferentiable. Not all concave functions are differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Another implicit assumption is that the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. For example the function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x(1-x)$ is both concave and positive.

Comment: @celtschk: you meant concave.

Comment: But without demanding strictly concave, and by assuming that I don't want constant functions, my claim will be true?
i.e.- concave, positive, and non-constant 

Thanks !

Comment: I received an answer for this below... Thanks ! I'll be glad to receive some guidance regarding the laplacian case!

Comment: See the answer by @copper.hat — in a nutshell, if you look at the function along a straight line, you'll get a one-dimensional function. Since that one cannot be positive unless constant, the whole function cannot be either (because it has a negative value on that line if not constant on it, and for a non-constant function you'll always find a line along which it is not constant).

Comment: Nonpositive Laplacian follows from superharmonic: the value at a point is $\ge$ the average around a circle centered there.  Equivalent if twice-differentiable.  Then (considering the plane to be the complex numbers) $\log|f(z)|$ is harmonic.

Answer (score 4):

There is no non-constant positive concave function on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

If $f$ is a concave function, then the difference ratio
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
$$
is a non-increasing function of both $x$ and $y$.

Suppose there are $x$ and $y$ so that $f(x)<f(y)$ and let $M=\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$.

---

If $x<y$, then $M>0$ and for all $z< x$, we have that
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}\ge\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=M\tag{1}
$$
therefore,
$$
f(z)\le f(y)+(z-y)M\tag{2}
$$
and $(2)$ says that for all $z< y-\frac{f(y)}{M}$, we have $f(z)<0$.

---

If $x>y$, then $M<0$ and for all $z>x$, we have that
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}\le\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=M\tag{3}
$$
therefore,
$$
f(z)\le f(y)+(z-y)M\tag{4}
$$
and $(4)$ says that for all $z>y-\frac{f(y)}{M}$, we have $f(z)<0$.

---

Thus no matter whether $x>y$ or $x<y$, we have that $f$ cannot stay positive.

**Superharmonic Functions**

A [superharmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function) is one whose Laplacian is non-positive everywhere. I believe this is what you mean by "the Laplacian case".

Since the case of harmonic functions can be handled using [Harnack's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_inequality), let's consider the case of strictly superharmonic functions; that is, ones for which $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Delta f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\lt0$.

Let $B(r,x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n:|y-x|\le r\}$. Then, by the [Divergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem),
$$
\int_{B(r,x)}\Delta f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\partial B(r,x)}\nabla f(y)\cdot\vec{n}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma(y)\tag{5}
$$
The right hand side of $(5)$ is the measure of $\partial B(r,x)$ times the rate of change of $m_f(r,x)$, the mean value of $f$ over $\partial B(r,x)$. The left hand side of $(5)$ is strictly negative past a certain $r_0$. Rewriting this, we get for $r\ge r_0$,
$$
\omega_{n-1}r^{n-1}\frac{\partial m_f(r,x)}{\partial r}\le C\lt0\tag{6}
$$
which leads to
$$
\frac{\partial m_f(r,x)}{\partial r}\le\frac{C}{\omega_{n-1}r^{n-1}}\tag{7}
$$
For $n\le2$, $(7)$ says that there can be no lower bound for $m_f(r,x)$, which means there can be no lower bound for $f$.

According to item $8)$ [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Subharmonic_function), a superharmonic function on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is bounded below is constant. However, the same is not true on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge3$. This agrees with $(7)$.

Comment: Thanks  a lot!  I'll update my assumptions...
What about the laplacian case?
Thanks !

Comment: That's excatly what I mean ! Do you know of any possible way to prove this?

Thanks !

Comment: @joshua: I've added a bit which explains the claim made in item $8)$ [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Subharmonic_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll read it depply on weekend ! Hope I'll figure it out ! 

Thanks Again!

Comment: OK. I have now read your answer, and I found several things difficult:
First of all, can you please explain why does your final conclousion is only true for $n \leq 2 $ ? I can't figure this out. 
In addition, can you please explain again how did you deduce what you said about the RHS of (5) ? 

Have you got any idea about standard PDE methods of proving this? Something like denoting $ v^\epsilon = u + \epsilon log(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} ) $ , where $u$ is a subharmonic function, and estaimating $\epsilon$ or something? 

Thanks again !

Comment: @joshua: $\nabla f(y)\cdot\vec{n}$ is the rate of change per unit distance of $f$ in the outward direction. Think of integrating $f$ over a sphere of radius $r$ with measure scaled so that the whole sphere has measure $1$, then over a sphere of radius $r+\mathrm{d}r$ whose measure is also scaled to $1$. The difference would be $\nabla f(y)\cdot\vec{n}\,\mathrm{d}r$ also integrated over a sphere whose measure was scaled to $1$. This is simply the difference of the mean of $f$ over a sphere of radius $r$ and a sphere of radius $r+\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: @joshua: In this way, the right hand side of $(5)$ is seen to be the area of a sphere of radius $r$ times the rate of change of the mean of $f$ over the sphere of radius $r$.

Comment: @joshua: Integrating $(7)$ from $r_0$ to $\infty$ yields the difference from $m_f(r_0,x)$ to $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}m_f(r,x)$. When $n\le2$, The integral of $(7)$ diverges and so there is no lower bound to $m_f(r,x)$. When $n\gt2$, we cannot make the same claim.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

Concavity (or convexity) is essentially a 'one dimensional' property in that you only need to consider behavior on a line. The ambient space is somewhat irrelevant (at least for concavity/convexity issues).

It is straightforward to establish that if $f$ is a concave real-valued function on a vector space, and bounded below, then $f$ is a constant. (In your question, the lower bound is $0$.)

To see this, suppose $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, and consider the (concave) function $\phi(t) = f(t x_2+(1-t)x_1)$. Then taking $t>1$, by concavity, we have
$$\phi(\frac{1}{t} t + (1-\frac{1}{t}) 0) \geq \frac{1}{t} \phi(t) + (1-\frac{1}{t}) \phi(0).$$
Multiplying across by $t$, and rearranging gives:
$$\phi(0) + t (\phi(1)-\phi(0)) \geq \phi(t).$$
Since $\phi(1)-\phi(0) = f(x_2)-f(x_1) < 0$, and $t>1$ was arbitrary, we see that $\phi$ is unbounded below, which is a contradiction. Hence $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Thanks ! But what about the Laplacian case? (i.e- I don't demand concavity, but non-positive laplacian)

Comment: But shouldn't the concavity condition only give that inequality for $0 < 1/t \le 1$, that is $t \ge 1$? Of course that doesn't invalidate the argument.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that, I did mean $t>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ strictly concave and twice diferentiable in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ então $v(x) = u(x,0)$ is strictly concave and twice diferentiable in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence assume negative value.