# $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. $f \geq 0$ and $f$ is midpoint concave, then how to prove $f$ is a constant function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

$f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $f \geq 0$ and $f$ satisfies $\frac12f(x_1)+\frac12f(x_2) \leq f(\frac{x_1+x_2}2)$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R$. How to prove that $f$ is a constant function?

Thanks in advance！

Comment: Are we assuming $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Not needed, Jensen-concave function bounded below is necessarily continuous.

Comment: Suppose there are $a,b$ with $f(a) > f(b)$. What can you say about $f(a + 2^k(b-a))$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $f(a+2^k(b-a)) \geq \frac{f(2a)+f(2^{k+1}(b-a))}{2}$?

Comment: Think in the other direction. We want an upper bound (that eventually becomes negative).

Comment: @DanielFischer Is it true that $f(a+2^k(b-a)) \leq f(a) + f(2^k(b-a))$, if $a,b>0$?

Comment: Maybe. What I was aiming at is $f(a + 2^k(b-a)) \leqslant f(a) + 2^k\cdot (??)$ with a negative $(??)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems that when $a,b>0, b-a>0$, $f(b) \leq f(b-a) + f(a)$, then $f(b) - f(a) \leq f(b-a)$. I still have difficulty proving that $f(b-a) <0$.

Comment: Forget $f(b-a)$. What about $f(b) - f(a)$? (And that regardless of whether any of $a,b,b-a$ is positive.)

Comment: @DanielFischer $f(b) - f(a) < 0$. But are we going from $f(a + 2^k(b-a)) \leq f(a) + 2^k f(b-a)$, and going to prove that $f(b-a)<0$?

Comment: No. We never look at $f(b-a)$. That might be positive for all we know.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK. Let me think about it again

Comment: [Related question about a concave function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165833/721644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose $f$ isn't constant, then exists $x_1 > x_2$ (it could be $x_1 < x_2$, the proof is analogous) such that $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, define $\Delta x = x_1 - x_2$ and $x_{i+1} = x_i - \Delta x$, then by concavity we have for every $i\geq1$:
$$ \frac{1}{2}(f(x_i) + f(x_{i+2})) \leq f(x_{i+1}) $$
$$ f(x_{i+1}) -f(x_{i+2}) \geq f(x_{i})-f(x_{i+1}) $$
Repeat the last inequality and we get:
$$ f(x_{i+1}) -f(x_{i+2}) \geq f(x_{1})-f(x_{2}) $$
Now we will use that $f\geq 0$:
$$f(x_1) - f(x_n) = (f(x_1)-f(x_{2})) + (f(x_{2})-f(x_{3})) + \cdots + (f(x_{n-1}) - f(x_n))$$
$$f(x_1) - f(x_n) \geq (n-1)(f(x_1)-f(x_2))$$
But it's possible to find $N$ such that $(N-1)(f(x_1)-f(x_2)) > f(x_1)$, then:
$$f(x_1) - f(x_N) \geq (N-1)(f(x_1)-f(x_2)) > f(x_1)$$
$$f(x_N) < 0$$
But we had $f \geq 0$, then $f$ must be constant.